# change transfer state in angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

angular universal have a state in json which is stocked in html generated
I would like to encrypt every link from the json in ServerTransferStateModule generated by angular universal. globally I want to hide those link from SSR . can I encrpyt links and after that decrypt them

any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can register a callback using `onSerialize` ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState#onserialize))

**Note**: if someone really wants to, they can still decrpyt these links (as you'll need to do it js side anyway)